# Почему пропадает часть кириллических букв при работе с формой через webbrowser?

Tags: python, кодировка, webbrowser, автоматизация

Автоматизирую форму через webbrowser (Python 2.7.9, Chrome, Windows). На сайте кодировка cp1251. 
Задача - набрать кириллический текст в input. 
Проблема - из текста пропадают буквы и, о, п, р, с, т, у, ф, х, ц, ч, ш щ, ъ, ы.

```
text = "Текст в поле"
obj_name_ru = browser.find_element_by_id("obj_name_ru")
obj_name_ru.send_keys(text)
```

Менял кодировку в заголовке файла программы (пробовал utf8 и cp1251), пробовал изначально задавать текст в юникоде - u"Текст в поле", пробовал перед отправкой текста в поле использовать text = unicode(text, "cp1251"). Все это не помогло решить проблему.

В чем может быть проблема? Куда смотреть? У кого-то было подобное?

Comment: Вы возможно путаете `selenium.webdriver` и встроенный `webbrowser` модуль. Используйте Unicode, чтобы работать с текстом в Питоне. Не нужно "пробовать" utf8 и cp1251—вы должны твёрдо знать какая кодировка используется вашим редактором, чтобы сохранить исходники, и что именно эта кодировка задекларирована наверху  файла—решайте одну проблему за раз. Создайте полный (но минимальный) пример, который демонстрирует проблему (пример html с формой, конкретный пример ввода, ожидаемый результат и что вместо этого получаете).